# Boost with box2d

Tags: boost, box2d

I'm trying to use boost in my box2d game. But when I'm creating b2world, boost crashes.

```
#include <Box2d/Box2D.h>
#include <boost/filesystem/operations.hpp>
#include <boost/filesystem/path.hpp>

namespace fs = boost::filesystem;


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  b2World *world = new b2World(b2Vec2(0.0f, -10.0f), true);

  fs::path full_path(fs::initial_path<fs::path>());

  delete world;

  return 0;
}
```

When I comment string with box2d or boost code, it works ok. But they don't want work together.

Error: Unhandled exception at 0x5d9031ea (msvcr90d.dll) in Game.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xccccccc0.

```
>   msvcr90d.dll!operator delete(void * pUserData=0xcccccccc)  Line 52 + 0x3 bytes  C++
    msvcp90d.dll!std::allocator<unsigned short>::deallocate(unsigned short * _Ptr=0xcccccccc, unsigned int __formal=3435973837)  Line 146 + 0x9 bytes   C++
    msvcp90d.dll!std::basic_string<unsigned short,std::char_traits<unsigned short>,std::allocator<unsigned short> >::_Tidy(bool _Built=true, unsigned int _Newsize=0)  Line 2168    C++
    msvcp90d.dll!std::basic_string<unsigned short,std::char_traits<unsigned short>,std::allocator<unsigned short> >::~basic_string<unsigned short,std::char_traits<unsigned short>,std::allocator<unsigned short> >()  Line 917 C++
    Game.exe!boost::filesystem3::path::~path()  + 0x2e bytes    C++
    Game.exe!main(int argc=1, char * * argv=0x003a4ca0)  Line 32 + 0x19 bytes   C++
    Game.exe!__tmainCRTStartup()  Line 582 + 0x19 bytes C
```

Produces only in debug mode.

It doesn't matter where I create b2World object: after full_path() or not. Error produces even I create b2World object in another class or file in project.

Comment: You will quickly find that if you don't include more than "it crashes", it is often impossible for us to help debug your error. How does it crash? Does it produce an error? Did you add a breakpoint to see if it gets past a certain line?

Comment: msvcr90d.dll!operator delete(void * pUs... Line 52
msvcp90d.dll!std::allocat...  Line 146 + 0x9 bytes
msvcp90d.dll!std::basic_string<unsigned short,std::char_traits<unsigned short>,std::allocator<unsign... Line 2168
msvcp90d.dll!std::basic_string<unsigned short,std::char_traits<unsigned short>,std::allocator<unsigned short> >::~basic_string<unsigned short,std::char_traits<unsigned short>,std::allocator<unsigned short> >()  Line 917
Game.exe!boost::filesystem3::path::~path()
Game.exe!main(int argc=1, char * * argv=0x002e4ca0)
There is call stack. Error produce only in debug mode.

Comment: @Raman: Put that in your answer and format it.

Comment: I can not, my reputation is less than 100 =)

Comment: @Raman: You can always edit your own question. It's other people's that takes reputation.

Comment: does it help if the box2d include comes after the boost includes?

Answer (score 0):

Well it will be very difficult for point you out to the exact cause of the problem but it seems that you have a heap corruption. It can be quite tricky to find the culprit (the piece of code that is overwriting or freeing some memory that it shouldn't) since the effects (crashes) can often be seen much later and in some unrelated parts of the code;

Have you tried other options under run-time library settings under the "code generation" tab? Sometimes mixing of different libraries with different CRTs can lead to crashes (although normaly you get a linking error).

Then if nothing helps I would suggest you to try to isolate the problem and create a minimal project where the problem shows up, it is time consuming but can help a lot since as already said these problems can be very hard to find.

From there you could also use some additional tools that can help in tracking heap corruptions. You can for example use gflags (from the Debugging Tools for Windows package) to activate the "page heap" option for your application, this will make the debugger break execution when a heap corruption is detected.

Comment: I don't use MFC. Please, pay more attention, please.

Comment: Ops my bad, don't know where I saw MFC, I edited my answer now. The rest still applies though - I think that you are dealing with a heap corruption, you can google or search Stack Overflow to get some tips on how to solve these problems (as already pointed out said it might be quite tricky and time consuming sometimes)